# python mahotas.imread reads a 2d image as 3d

Tags: python, image-processing, mahotas

I have an image saved by another code of mine. The image is a normal JPG file. I saved it with imsave.

now when I'm reading it in another code, it seems to be 3d :S

the image is [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18284302/normal.jpg).

and a simple code to read it is this :

```
import mahotas

img = mahotas.imread('d:/normal.jpg')
print img.shape, img.dtype
```

Comment: By 3d, do you mean x*y*3? In that case it is read as a color image and you just need to convert it to grayscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading the jpg as greyscale like this:

```
mahotas.imread('d:/normal.jpg', as_grey = True)
```

Comment: thanks. that works. but could I somehow save it as grey scale instead ?

Comment: @Kiarash: I don't think there's such a thing as a greyscale JPG. If you want to encode the image as greyscale, choose another image format such as GIF, PNG, TIF.

Answer (score 2):

(Author of mahotas here).

The suggestion by Junuxx is correct:

```
mahotas.imread('file.jpg', as_grey=True)
```

This reads the RGB file and converts it to grey scale by a weighted average of the components (they are not equally weighted, but use typical coefficients that attempt to be perceptually more accurate).

The alternative (which I rather prefer) is:

```
im = mahotas.imread('file.jpg')
im = im[:,:,0]
```

I assume that all the channels have the same values and just use the first one.